# Retrieving a specific XML node, jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Relatively new to dealing with XML in jQuery. I am trying to retrieve a specific node from an XML file based on an attribute in its parent element. Here is the XML (short version):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <members>
           <member row="1">
              <firstName>John</firstName>
              <lastName>Smith</lastName>
              <status>Active</status>
              <title>Member</title>
              <memberSince>August, 2011</memberSince>
           </member>
          <member row="2">
              <firstName>Jane</firstName>
              <lastName>Smith</lastName>
              <status>Active</status>
              <title>Member</title>
              <memberSince>October, 2011</memberSince>
           </member>
     </members>
```

I understand the basics of how to retrieve XML using `$.get()` in jQuery but cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve just the details for, say, `member row="2"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here is the jQuery I am using for this simple test, the alert returns as `undefined`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(
        'member_xml.php', function($xml) {
            $xml = $($xml);
            row = 2;
            var test = $xml.find('member[row="' + row + '"]').attr('firstName');
            alert(test);
        },
        'xml'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$xml` is your XML wrapped in a jQuery object:

```
$xml.find('member[row="2"]')
```

Will select the row you want to manipulate.

```
$xml.find('member[row="2"] firstName').text(); //returns Jane
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jTJU/1/) is an example of this working. XML selectors work similarly to selecting elements from you DOM; most of what you know about that can be applied here.

Comment: Looks like this is on the right track but I cannot seem to obtain the text using the above code. It returns 'undefined' when I try using it in an alert message - `var test = $xml.find('member[row="2"].attr('firstName');`

Answer (score 2):

parse the xml using [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
var xml = '<members>\
           <member row="1">\
              <firstName>John</firstName>\
              <lastName>Smith</lastName>\
              <status>Active</status>\
              <title>Member</title>\
              <memberSince>August, 2011</memberSince>\
           </member>\
          <member row="2">\
              <firstName>Jane</firstName>\
              <lastName>Smith</lastName>\
              <status>Active</status>\
              <title>Member</title>\
              <memberSince>October, 2011</memberSince>\
           </member>\
     </members>';


    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    $member = $xml.find('member[row="2"]').find('firstName').text();
console.log($member);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsFUz/1/)

Comment: Okay, this works great as in your example, but when I try to reference the external file (member_xml.php), it says invalid XML? What am I missing?