# Jquery html() and reserved element names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

In the result of an AJAX call I have multiple fields in XML format. One of the nodes called `Request` contains an entire XML structure that I want to display.

```
var request = $(xml).find("Request").html()
```

The above line returns me the content of the Request node. However, one of the tags is called `<INPUT>`. Which is ofcourse being interpreted as an HTML-element.
This is the result I get in my `var request` :

```
<root>
    <input>
        <i_date>20150316</i_date>
        <i_order_nr>110535</i_order_nr>
        <i_sequence_number>0057</i_sequence_number>
        <i_time>105016</i_time>
        <i_uom>KG</i_uom>

</root>
```

As you can see the closing `</input>` tag is missing. It is present in the response of my Ajax call. But by using JQuery `.html()` it is removed. How can I get the content of the `Request` node without Jquery interpretting the tags?

Comment: I would try some dirty hack like `$(xml).find("Request").html().replace(/input/g , "input2")`, so you get an `<input2></input2>` tag or something, which won't get interpreted. Comes with no warranties.

Comment: It is not the problem with `.html()` but with `$(xml)` itself. And it is time to use hacks like replacing `<input>` with `<input2>` or to use another technologies for parsing.

Comment: @JeremyThille 1. it will be better to replace `<input>` String, not just `input`. 2. It has to be done in the original string **before** `$(xml)` is executed.

Comment: If `xml` is a string, do a regex before doing `$(xml)` to replace all `<input>`, something like `xml.replace(/<input\s+?([^>]+)?>/gi, '<item $1>')` - **untested**

Comment: what is your objective? If you want to show that XML in plain text use `.text` instead of `.html`, if you want to get it parsed by the browser (it's odd because it's not HTML) you shouldn't fix it in client side, it's in invalid HTML, you should fix it at your source.

Comment: Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168782/retrieving-a-specific-xml-node-jquery) link.

Comment: Why not just HTML escape the contents so they dont get "re-parsed".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. I eventually went with the dirty way. I don't like doing this stuff but it seems  it is the only option.

```
xml= xml
     .replace(/<input>/g , "<input2>")
     .replace(/<\/input>/g , "<\/input2>");
var request = $(xml).find("Request").html()
              .replace(/<input2>/g , "<input>")
              .replace(/<\/input2>/g , "<\/input>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 `var response = $('<div/>').text($(xml).find("Request").html()).html();`
It should create a div element add your xml as text to that div(which in order would escape html tags) and then the html() function gets you the escaped text.

Comment: I tested this. It escaped the tags but the closing </input>  tag is still missing